# Updating object at program level within class

Tags: c#, system-tray, notifyicon

I have a program that runs in the system tray that communicates with our server and "syncs" data based on a users preferenced jobs. The idea is similar to Dropbox, but for our surveying software called 12d Synergy. The idea is that users can sync data without needing to navigate through the softwares Client.
I want to add the functionality so that when the program is syncing, the icon in the system tray changes to indicate that its still syncing, but i can't figure out how to get access to the original object within the portion of the program where the event is located.
My program stucture is as follows (in c#):

**Program.cs**

```
using (ProcessingIcon pi = new ProcessingIcon())
{
   pi.SetIcon(Resources._12d);
   pi.Display();

   Application.Run();
}
```

**ProcessingIcon.cs**

```
    NotifyIcon ni;
    public void SetIcon(Icon path)
    {
        ni.Icon = path;
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        ni.Text = "Sunrise Surveying 12d Synergy Sync Tool";
        ni.Visible = true;

        ni.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenus().Create();
    }
```

**ContextMenus.cs**

```
    public ContextMenuStrip Create()
    {
        // Sync Now
        item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        item.Text = "Sync Now";
        item.Click += new EventHandler(syncNow_Click);
        item.Image = Resources.Sync.ToBitmap();
        cms.Items.Add(item);
     }

    void syncNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        string[] jobs = Sync.GetSharedFiles();
        string[] files = Sync.GetDataToSync(jobs);
        Sync.SyncData(files);

    }
```

What i want to happen, is in the syncNow_click, call the ProcessingIcon.SetIcon() to change the icon, but i can't figure out how to get access to an object that exists 3 layers up in the program.

I should note that i am not a programmer, i'm a surveyor with an interest in programming. I am completely self taught, so i know there is probably something relatively simple i'm missing. This is also my first post in StackOverflow, so i'm not 100% how to use this site to the full capability, so if this has been answered somewhere i apologise.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So i worked out a way to answer my own question. Just putting it here in case anyone has the same issue. It turned out to be incredibly simple, and purely just by me not fully understanding the classes/objects structure.

I added a constructor for my ContextMenus object which passed in the the NotifyIcon that was calling it. This was passed to a NotifyIcon variable in that class which i could then access.

```
class ContextMenus
{
        public NotifyIcon ni;

        public ContextMenus(NotifyIcon ni)
        {
            this.ni = ni;
        }
}
```